# What standard defines required PCB clearance for mains vs. low voltage, isolated traces?

Tags: pcb

Probably this has been asked before, I am not clear about regulations (standards).
I have a chipset close by 220VAC mains pins, impossible to move away due to other mechanical constraints.

Actually, I have ~2mm clearance.
The PCB will be coated with solder mask (related to this post)
[What is the right PCB clearance when using mains (220VAC)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/586398/what-is-the-right-pcb-clearance-when-using-mains-220vac)

What I can do is to have a slot in PCB, to isolate more from pins to mains.

Other ways, I have to stack 2 PCBs, one containing mains connector and other, low voltage.

If anyone knows who precise regulates this, what standard, maybe there is a chance to use a single board.

Tnaks in advance,

[image]

Comment: The standard is listed in the question you linked and, it is downloadable (earlier versions).

Comment: hmmm.. just a picture on my side, no link to download

Comment: I don't see a standard in the link, and the caption in the image just says IPC-2221, an outdated industry (non regulatory) standard.

Comment: The X distance is 32.283 mils.  But isn't that the distance between the center of the pins/pads, and not the spacing?

Comment: [IPC 2221 A](http://www-eng.lbl.gov/~shuman/NEXT/CURRENT_DESIGN/TP/MATERIALS/IPC-2221A(L).pdf)

Comment: Lots of standards define such dimensional and other requirements. They are market- and application-specific.  So, first you need to figure out what regulatory requirements does your device fall into in the target markets. Then you need to get the relevant standards. Unfortunately, those are not cheap at all. If you want to go by the book, think several thousands of dollars whether you do it yourself or get a consultant who works in that field to help you out. A consultant may be cheaper in the long run.

Comment: What Andy said.  FYI, our company has created its own internal set of documents for PWB design, tailored from various standards referenced in IPC2220, for our aerospace products.  Sometimes our customer will impose their own set of requirements to follow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on product and market.  For a general starting point, consider IEC 62368-1.

Beware: depending on process, and standard being met, solder mask may not count as insulation.  It is prone to form thin films, or pinholes.  Standards may require an inspection process, which as far as I know, fabs don't do, or not usually.

You can almost certainly do that with potting, but that's probably a lot of work/cost.  Another possibility is a milled PCB slot, which increases creepage distance but not clearance; a strip of polyester or FR-4 could be glued into the slot to enforce more of both.

Also, you may simply not want to do it anyway: consider the effect of mains EFT, and the capacitance between pads.  Transients could disturb readings, or even induce device crash/reset/latchup.